# Python: ftputil only uploads 36kb of 18mb file

Tags: python, ftp

ftputil is the bomb.... almost!

My call to host.upload below works great on small text files. For larger files (I am working mostly with 9-20 gb files) there are no exceptions, and no errors, but only 10-40kb is uploaded.

From the same client I can upload the large files fine using filezilla client, so I know there are no problems of that kind. Both filezilla client and ftputil are using active mode ftp (firewall has ftp fixup, and one of the firewalls involved is causing a problem for passive)

How to solve?

```
class MySession(ftplib.FTP):

    def __init__(self, ftpServer, ftpUser, ftpPassword, ftpPort):
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self)
        self.set_debuglevel(ftpDebugLevel)
        self.set_pasv(False)
        self.connect(ftpServer, ftpPort)
        self.login(ftpUser, ftpPassword)

host = ftputil.FTPHost(ftpServer, ftpUser, ftpPassword, ftpPort, session_factory=MySession) 

file = '18MBfile.zip'
print('ftp file to upload is:' + file + ' -- ' + join(dirpath,file) + ' -- ' + os.path.basename(file))
upload = host.upload(join(dirpath,file), destDir + os.path.basename(file))  # local, remote -- for remote: extract just file name from full path+filename
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `ftputil`. For fancy stuff it's a lot simpler than raw `ftplib`… but all you're doing is uploading a single file to a fixed location, and you're writing 8x as much `ftplib` code as `ftputil` code anyway, so why not just do it all in `ftplib` in the first place?

Comment: Also, can you at least _test_ it with the equivalent plain `ftplib` code to narrow down where the problem is happening?